# ScrollView doesn't allow to scroll unless the children components are Button or Touchable

Tags: react-native, scrollview

My  component is not working unless I change the children components to one of these types Button, TouchableOpacity or TouchableWithoutFeedback.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
   <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true} >
         <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
         <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
         <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
         <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
         <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
      </ScrollView>
   </View>
</View>
```

The strange is I cannot reproduce when create new project. New project with this code chunk is work.
The different between my current project, which is not working, and the new project is some libraries such as camera, axios, ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is may be there is other **touchable** which steals user’s *touch event* that's why you can not scroll the ScrollView. I guess you just need to add `onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}` to the View which wraps the intended ScrollView. Can you please try below code:

```
   <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
      <ScrollView >
        <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
        <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
        <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
        <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
        <View style={{width: 314, height:187, marginRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
      </ScrollView>
   </View>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Have a tried to apply max-height for vertical scrolling here `<View style={{flex: 1}}> `?

Comment: Yes, I had similar problem, I had Touchable opacity above scroll view